# Программный отступ margin

Tags: java, android

нужно отступить от нижнего правого угла, но если в view посадить bottom и right любое значение, то ничего не происходит, а отступ идет, только если поставить top и left

```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImageView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            80,
            80);

    paramsImageView.setMargins(0,0,320,320);
    hintImageView.setLayoutParams(paramsImageView);
```

Comment: hintImageView стоит в нижнеп правом углу вашего контейнера? можно включить отображение границ (опции разработчика) и будет видно есть ли отступы в вашего ImageView или нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
 paramsImageView.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        paramsImageView.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```